# Tiff: algorithm to decode PackBits

Tags: image-processing, compression, tiff

While working on a routine to open TIFF files generated by a microscope software in Matlab I got stuck on reading compressed images. At this point it's a matter of honour for me to understand how to decode tiff data in the PackBits format.

With little experience in real computer science, I have troubles understanding the guidelines in the TIFF documentation, more specifically:

> In the inverse routine, it is best to encode a 2-byte repeat run as a
> replicate run except when preceded and followed by a literal run. In
> that case, it is best to merge the three runs into one literal run.
> Always encode 3-byte repeats as replicate runs. That is the essence of
> the algorithm. Here are some additional rules:
>
> • Pack each row
> separately. Do not compress across row boundaries.
>
> • The number of uncompressed bytes per row is defined to be (ImageWidth + 7) / 8. If the uncompressed bitmap is required to have an even number of bytes per row, decompress into word-aligned buffers.
>
> • If a run is larger than 128 bytes, encode the remainder of the run as one or more additional replicate runs.

source: https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion-packbits.htm

I understand how to implement the pseudocode, and decode a sample string compressed with PackBits in Matlab. However, I'm lost during parsing a chunk of 16 bit, greyscale Tiff file. My question is how do I go about it? I don't really understand what it means in *replicate run*, neither what is a *word-aligned buffer*.
When I start decoding the data form form the first byte, I just get nonsense.

Help with understanding the logic of decompression will be appreciated, also a link to code decompressing the Tiff PackBits will be helpful.

~Jakub

**Edit**: I got the decompression algorithm to work, my error was to interpret the bytes wrongly, here is a code, if anyone will be interested in a similar problem in the future.

```
Tiff_file = 'compressed.tiff';
%open and read tiff file file
imInfo = imfinfo(Tiff_file);
fId = fopen(Tiff_file);
im = fread(fId);
fclose(fId);

%parse the file
output = zeros(1,imInfo.Width * imInfo.Height * 2);%preallocate
thisLoc = 1;
for strip = 1:length(imInfo.StripOffsets)
    thisLength = imInfo.StripByteCounts(strip);
    thisOffset = imInfo.StripOffsets(strip);
    thisStrip = im(thisOffset + 1 : thisOffset + thisLength);
    pntr = 1; %start at the first byte
    %loop throught the coded data
    while pntr <  thisLength
        key = thisStrip(pntr);
        if key >= 129
            key = 257 - key;
            datTmp = repmat(thisStrip(pntr+1), [1 key]);
            output(thisLoc:thisLoc+key-1) = datTmp;
            thisLoc = thisLoc+key;
            pntr = pntr + 2;
        elseif key == 128 %nope
            pntr = pntr + 1;
        else
            datTmp = thisStrip(pntr + 1 : pntr + 1 + key);
            output(thisLoc:thisLoc+key) = datTmp;
            thisLoc = thisLoc + key+1;
            pntr = pntr + key + 2;
        end
    end
end

im = typecast(uint8(output),'uint16');
%reshape decoded data.
im = reshape(im,[imInfo.Width imInfo.Height])';
```

Comment: The guidelines in the TIFF documentation you quoted are not really relevant to your case: they either concern encoding image bytes or decoding bilevel images. You should be able to use your implementation of the pseudocode, assuming that it is correct and the compression was done correctly. Besides that, it does not make any sense to compress 16-bit microscopy data using PackBits...

Comment: Ok, because you assured me that the algorithm will work, using the instructions for unsigned bytes (as in: http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/PackBits) I got to decode the image. I was trying to use signed bytes before, and that was an issue. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @RecBCD Nice to see that you could answer your own question. This site works best if you would post that comment also as answer (and mark it as accepted). Comments are mostly only for discussing questions or answers.